# Tranforming a string to an integer in Microsoft Excel

Tags: excel

**I assume this is just due to my own stupidity**

I am trying to figure out how to convert a row of data which is made up of two different strings, "man" and "woman" into the variables "0" and "1". I am trying to do this because I am doing a PCA analysis on the dataset.

I have not been able to find this anywhere, so I thought I would pose the question here.

Comment: Have you tried any coding yet?  We can help you, but you've got to make a bit of an effort.  Also, knowing a bit more would be helpful.  What does your data set look like, for example?

Comment: Does the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a formula like this: `=IF(C3="man", 1, 0)`

Take for example the image below.

[image]

In D3, type that formula and you'll get 1 for man and 0 for woman. In your case, you want it reverse. So, change your formula to `=IF(C3="man", 0, 1)`. Then, copy that formula to other relevant cells.